# How do you write every paintComponent call simultaneously to BufferedImage?

Tags: java, swing, awt, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

How do you write every every repaint call (direct or not) by a `JPanel`-type (i.e. a custom class which `extends`/inherits from `JPanel`) to a `BufferedImage` ?

Doing this sort of thing inside the custom class' `paintComponent` does not work:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Graphics2D G2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    // ... draw objects

    BufferedImage imageBuffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    G2 = imageBuffer.createGraphics();

    // Which doesn't work, because with that method it seems you would
    // need to call paint() on Graphics2D reference here. 
    // And to do so would then throw an Illegal Exception.
}
```

The resulting `BufferedImage` is the correct size of the `JPanel`-type class which calls `paintComponent`, but the image is black (i.e. empty) - which is entirely logical because `createGraphics()` alone does nothing.

I know of Rob Camick's [ScreenImage](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) code - but that seems intended for a single screenshot at initialisation of the program.

What leaves me confused is that what `paintComponent` does must be held in memory before being displayed on-screen... So is there a way of grabbing that every time and saving it into a `BufferedImage` ?

Comment: Can't you just do your custom painting onto the `BufferedImage` using its own `Graphics`, save it, then `drawImage()` that `BufferedImage` you just created onto the component using the `paintComponent()` Graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this approach?  The difference from you posted code is that you need to do all your custom drawing onto your `BufferedImage`.  Then you draw just one thing onto the component: the `BufferedImage`.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    BufferedImage imageBuffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics imageG2 = imageBuffer.createGraphics();

    // do custom painting onto imageG2...

    // save imageBuffer

    g2.drawImage(imageBuffer, 0, 0, this);  // draw onto component
}
```

Comment: This just flat out ***works.*** Simple and direct solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The description and some details may not be entirely clear. But it basically sounds like you wanted to create a component that can be used like a normal `JPanel`, but everything that is painted in the `paintComponent` method should also be saved as a `BufferedImage`.

There are different solutions for this. You could make dedicated calls, like

```
myComponent.paintComponent(bufferedImageGraphics);
```

and process the image accordingly, as proposed in one answer. Another answer suggested creating a custom `paintComponent` method that does the image handling.

However, I'd like to propose the following solution: You could create a `ImageSavingComponent` class that extends `JPanel`. In this class, you don't override the `paintComponent` method, but the `paint` method. The `paint` method does two things:

- It calls `super.paint(bufferedImageGraphics)`, painting into an image
- It calls `super.paint(componentGraphics)`, painting to the screen

This way, you may simply extend this class, and implement the `paintComponent` method like you would do for any `JPanel`. The image handling can be done completely transparently.

In the example below, I added a `Consumer` interface that receives the images and handles them appropriately. If the `Consumer` is `null`, then no images will be produced. For the test, I created an implementation of this interface that simply stores the images in files every 200ms. (This interface may be replaced with the Java 8 `Consumer` interface, if desired)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ImageSavingComponentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final ImageSavingComponent c = new ExampleImageSavingComponent();
        f.getContentPane().add(c);

        final Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                c.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        final Consumer<? super BufferedImage> consumer = new ImageSaver();
        final JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton("Capture");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b.isSelected()) {
                    c.setConsumer(consumer);
                } else {
                    c.setConsumer(null);
                }
            }
        });
        c.add(b);

        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ImageSaver implements Consumer<BufferedImage>
{
    private int counter = 0;
    private long previousFrameMillis = -1;
    private long intervalMillis = 200;

    @Override
    public void accept(BufferedImage t) {

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() < previousFrameMillis + intervalMillis)
        {
            return;
        }
        previousFrameMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String fileName = String.format("image%04d.png", counter);
        counter++;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ImageIO.write(t, "png", fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}




class ExampleImageSavingComponent extends ImageSavingComponent {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        double time = (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2000) / 2000.0;
        double ca = Math.cos(time * Math.PI * 2);
        double sa = Math.sin(time * Math.PI * 2);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        double d = 50;
        int x = getWidth() / 2 + (int) (ca * d);
        int y = getHeight() / 2 + (int) (sa * d);
        int r = 10;
        g.fillOval(x - r, y - r, r + r, r + r);
    }
}

interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}

class ImageSavingComponent extends JPanel {
    private Consumer<? super BufferedImage> consumer;

    void setConsumer(Consumer<? super BufferedImage> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public final void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (consumer != null && getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getWidth(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D imageGraphics = image.createGraphics();
            super.paint(imageGraphics);
            imageGraphics.dispose();
            consumer.accept(image);
        }
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is such an expansive answer, I'm sorry that I can't accept more than one answer.

Comment: @BenjaminR No problem. The accepted answer to me seems to be completely different to what you originally asked for, but when you are satisfied with it, it is obviously exactly what you have been looking for. However, if this is what you have been looking for, your question indeed is a duplicate.

Comment: I don't know... your interpretation of my question seems to be answered most *efficiently* by whiskeyspider's answer. It feels wrong to tick your one instead just to cover my behind so if the question needs to be flagged, I'd rather take the hit for a duplicate answer than be dishonourable... Thanks again, though. I'd love to see the exact duplicate because I used the exact keywords of my question subject line. Maybe that's the problem/ambiguity? Perhaps it should be "How do you write every paintComponent call simultaneously to BufferedImage?" -- that seems more congruous w/ the question text.

Comment: @BenjaminR Sure, I may have overrated some statements or made implicit assumptions. Again: No problem from my side.

Comment: JPanel is ImageObserver, please paint for Swing JComponent?, super.paint(g) should be 1st code line in standard code, basically every of Animation in Java Swing in last year contains answer/comment by MadProgrammer with link to his code

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not sure in how far this is related to `ImageObserver`. And it should not matter whether `super.paint(g)` is the first or the last line, given that the lines before that one do nothing that affects what is visible on the screen. Do you think that there are serious flaws with how this is solved?

Answer (score 0):

You must create the `BufferedImage` outside the paint function of your component, and then call this paint function with the `BufferedImage` graphics as parameter.

```
BufferedImage imageBuffer = new BufferedImage(comp.getWidth(), cmp.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
cmp.paint(imageBuffer.getGraphics());
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only be called once, as opposed to every time paintComponent is called (i.e. in sync with it)?